# Is it Possible to find elements through regex in Scrapy just like in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to return all elements which have a particular text that satisfies regex. Just like in BeautifulSoup

```
data = BeautifulSoup(result.text,'html.parser')

urls = [x.get('href')
        for x in data.find(class_='newspaper-mainlisting').findAll('a', text = re.compile('\d*[\W-]Business'))]
```

How can I achieve this through Scrapy?

Comment: Have you tried using xpaths? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384382/scrapy-select-xpath-with-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression functions inside an xpath using an EXSLT extension.

From [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-exslt-extensions):

> Being built atop lxml, Scrapy selectors support some EXSLT extensions
> and come with these pre-registered namespaces to use in XPath
> expressions:
>
> ```
> +--------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
> | prefix |              namespace               |        usage        |
> +--------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
> | re     | http://exslt.org/regular-expressions | regular expressions |
> | set    | http://exslt.org/sets                | set manipulation    |
> +--------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
> ```

For your particular use, you will probably want something like this:

```
//*[@class='newspaper-mainlisting']//a[re:test(text(), '\d*[\W-]Business')]/@href
```